# Compiling the DotGnu

Tags: linux, compilation

I'm having trouble compiling the DotGNU, well .... when I compile the PNET, I get the following error of autoconfig:

```
configure.ac: 25: error: m4_copy: will not overwrite defined macro: _AC_ARG_VAR_PRECIOUS
```

And because of that (I believe) I can not compile the rest of project, then I wonder, how can I fix this?

I appreciate the help (:

Comment: Maybe you need a newer or older auto* tools? I've found that some projects are extremely picky about specific versions of the tools. :(

Comment: So, I tried to use the tools specified in INSTALL, but, I got the same error :/